# In bootstrap, how can I pass a value into a form which in a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm now creating a university search website. User enter the key word will return results and put those results into the card. It will have a 'Add review' button. After user click the button, it will pop up a modal which contain a form with two blank. The first blank is the name of the university. The name of the university must be pre-filled. I had tried several ways but still can't get a correct way.

Here are part of HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="universitycard"> <!-- place holder -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add review</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="University Name" class="col-form-label">University Name:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="universitynameinput" value="" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here are the JS code:

```
function makeApiCall(page){
    var keyword = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
    console.log(document.getElementById('user_input').value); // for debug using
    var url = 'http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name='+ keyword;
    $.ajax({url: url, dataType: "json"}).then(function(university) {
        console.log(university)
        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            console.log(university[i].name)
            document.getElementById('universitycard').innerHTML +=
            `<div class="card" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title" id = "universityinfo" >${university[i].name}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> ${university[i].country} </p>
                    <a href="${university[i].web_pages}" class="btn btn-warning">University Website</a>
                    <br></br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id = "${university[i].name}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Add Rewiew</button>
                </div>
            </div>`
       
        }

    })
}
function clearpage(){ //refresh page when click the submit
    document.getElementById('universitycard').innerHTML="";
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Add Rewiew").click(function(){
        $("#universitynameinput").val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: The fact that the form is in a modal isn't relevant--it's all just part of the DOM. You'd just target the element as usual.

Comment: I don't see any code here that attempts to update the value of `#universitynameinput`. Where is that?

Comment: `'.Add Rewiew'` is an invalid selector.  Classes cannot have spaces in their name (or should not).  A space in a selector denotes a(n indrect) child relationship between the first selector and the second one.

Comment: I also tried this way: `$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        $("#universitynameinput").val($(event.relatedTarget).data('id'));` But it also no use.

Comment: @Taplar So what should be an valid selector under my case?

Comment: I'm not clear on what element you are trying to target with that selector.

Comment: If code is  HTML, CSS, and JS make a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

As you are divs are created dynamically you need to bind it with **static** element in your *DOM* i.e document,body,any divs etc . Also , give a **class** to your modal button i.e : `addreview` then use `.attr('id')` to get id value and assign same to your input-box inside modal.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose this is your json arry
var university = [{
  "country": "United States",
  "web_pages": ["http://www.usafa.af.mil/", "http://www.usafa.edu/"],
  "state-province": null,
  "alpha_two_code": "US",
  "name": "United States Air Force Academy",
  "domains": ["usafa.af.mil", "usafa.edu"]
}, {
  "country": "Kenya",
  "web_pages": ["http://www.usiu.ac.ke/"],
  "state-province": null,
  "alpha_two_code": "KE",
  "name": "United States International University",
  "domains": ["usiu.ac.ke"]
}, {
  "country": "United States",
  "web_pages": ["http://www.usna.edu/"],
  "state-province": null,
  "alpha_two_code": "US",
  "name": "United States Naval Academy",
  "domains": ["usna.edu"]
}, {
  "country": "United States",
  "web_pages": ["http://www.usma.edu/"],
  "state-province": null,
  "alpha_two_code": "US",
  "name": "United States Military Academy",
  "domains": ["usma.edu"]
}, {
  "country": "United States",
  "web_pages": ["http://www.usmma.edu/"],
  "state-province": null,
  "alpha_two_code": "US",
  "name": "United States Merchant Marine Academy",
  "domains": ["usmma.edu"]
}, {
  "country": "United States",
  "web_pages": ["http://www.uscga.edu/"],
  "state-province": null,
  "alpha_two_code": "US",
  "name": "United States Coast Guard Academy",
  "domains": ["uscga.edu"]
}]

makeApiCall();

function makeApiCall(page) {
  // var keyword = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
  // console.log(document.getElementById('user_input').value); // for debug using
 // var url = 'http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=United States';
  /*$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json"
  }).then(function(university) {*/
  //console.log(university)
  for (var i = 0; i < university.length; i++) {
    //console.log(university[i].name)
    //added class for button addreview
    document.getElementById('universitycard').innerHTML +=
      `<div class="card" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title" id = "universityinfo" >${university[i].name}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> ${university[i].country} </p>
                    <a href="${university[i].web_pages}" class="btn btn-warning">University Website</a>
                    <br></br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addreview" id = "${university[i].name}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Add Rewiew</button>
                </div>
            </div>`

  }

  /*})*/
}


//onlick of addreview buttn
$(document).on("click", ".addreview", function() {
  //assign value inside input-box
  $("#universitynameinput").val($(this).attr('id'));
  $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="universitycard">
    <!-- place holder -->

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add review</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
              <label for="University Name" class="col-form-label">University Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="universitynameinput" value="" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```